# Mule ESB - servlet:inbound-endpoint error

Tags: mule

In my mule application, I replaced HTTP inbound endpoints with Servlet inbound endpoints, so I can deploy mule application on JBoss. Now when JBoss starts I'm getting this error message:

```
2012-08-16 12:13:00,416 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/oms]] (main)
Line 27 in XML document from request_flows.xml is invalid; 
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'servlet:inbound-endpoint'. 
One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-source, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' 
is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 27 in XML document from request_flows.xml is    invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content   was found starting with element 'servlet:inbound-endpoint'. One  of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-source, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected. 


    <flow name="ParcelRequestFlow" doc:name="ParcelRequestFlow">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="http://localhost:80/parcel" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Parcel Servlet"/>
    <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="Body to Parameter Map"/>
    <transformer ref="RequestParametersValidator1" doc:name="Validator"/>
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="messageSelectCountMessageId" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/plain" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Verify MessageId"/>
    <transformer ref="MessageIdValidator" doc:name="MessageId Validator"/>
    <transformer ref="parcelPayloadTransformer" doc:name="Parcel Payload Transformer"/>
    <message-properties-transformer scope="session" doc:name="Add PAYLOAD_OBJECT header">
        <add-message-property key="payload_object" value="#[payload]"/>
        <add-message-property key="payload_id" value="#[bean:parcelDetails.UPID]"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <transformer ref="ParcelBeanValidator" doc:name="ParcelBeanValidator"/>
    <transformer ref="MessagePropertyTransformer" doc:name="Message Property Transformer"/>
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="parcelInsert" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/plain" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Create DB Message Parcel"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="insurance.queue" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="queue.vm.connector" mimeType="text/plain" doc:name="Insurance Queue"/>
    <transformer ref="MessagePropertyTransformer" doc:name="Message Property Transformer"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="parcel.queue" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="queue.vm.connector" mimeType="text/plain" doc:name="Parcel Queue"/>
    <transformer ref="HttpResponseSucCessTransformer" doc:name="Return SUCCESS" />
    <custom-exception-strategy class="com.pb.oms.mule.exception.HttpRequestExceptionStrategy"></custom-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to declare the `servlet` namespace:

```
xmlns:servlet="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet"

...

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet/current/mule-servlet.xsd
```

and to have the Servlet transport JAR in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you. 

Now I have LinkageError:

2012-08-19 00:04:20,304 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/oms]] (main) Error creating bean with name '_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap' defined in default-mule-config.xml: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "STRING" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants, and the class loader (instance of <

Comment: Looks like typical a JBoss classloading quagmire. You must be very careful with the WAR you build and not include in it any JAR that is provided by JBoss.